# AngularJS - view not updating after scope change

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with some data via Firebase, and for some reason when the value changes on the server, the scope is getting updated in my console, however the angular view is not updating.

I've tried some different approaches including wrapping the reference to the scope in a `$timeout` & `$apply`, but still no solution. I've worked with angular many times and I've never ran into this behavior before. There's only one controller in the app.

*js*

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){

    $scope.publishedItems =[];
    var fbRef = firebase.database().ref('stories/' + storyId + "/correspondents").orderByChild('published').equalTo(true);
    fbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    //update scope

    $scope.publishedItems = snapshot.val();

    console.log($scope.publishedItems)// this logs the correct data, however the markup is not changing

});
```

*html*

```
 <div ng-controller="someCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="item in publishedItems">
        {{item}}
      </div>
 </doc>
```

**resolved**

So after some debugging, it turned out I had a function running outside of the Angular app that was appending some markup to the dom which was interfering with Angulars digest cycle.

Working as expected now

Comment: can you please create https://codepen.io/ example? and $scope.$apply migh help you

Comment: @ShirishPatel  I added a snippet although I didn't expose my firebase ref.

Comment: you can use $watchCollection() on the publishedItems, and it will start watching the each changes on the array.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming snapshot.val() returns something you need to trigger a digest cycle to determine changes since firebase callback is executed outside angular

```
fbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.publishedItems = snapshot.val();
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, yup, I've tried that and same result.  Still is not updating in the view.

Comment: that's wierd, you definitely need a call to $apply, try posting a link to a plunkr with the complete code

Comment: Yeh, never experienced this. Yeh Im gonna have to create a plunkr with another firebase instance.

Comment: of course I created a plunked and it worked.  The only main diffferebxe between the plunkr is the data is being manipulated from another source....would that make a difference?

Comment: so I just rebooted and everything worked as expected.. weird

Comment: glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.publishedItems = [];
    $scope.$watchCollection('publishedItems', function(newCol, oldCol, scope) {
        console.log(newCol, oldCol, scope);
    });
    var fbRef = firebase.database().ref('stories/' + storyId + "/correspondents").orderByChild('published').equalTo(true);
    fbRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var pubItems = snapshot.val();
        //update scope

        $scope.publishedItems = pubItems;

        console.log($scope.publishedItems)// this logs the correct    data, however the markup is not changing

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to update you binding , so you need to use [$scope.$apply()](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){

    $scope.publishedItems =[];
    var fbRef = firebase.database().ref('stories/' + storyId + "/correspondents").orderByChild('published').equalTo(true);
    fbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    //update scope

    $scope.publishedItems = snapshot.val();



    console.log($scope.publishedItems)// this logs the correct data, however the markup is not changing

});
   $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Hi, yup, I've tried that and same result.  Still is not updating in the view.

Comment: I added a snippet although i didnt expose my firebase ref.. but you can at least see where I'm having the issue.

Comment: @gregdevs you are missing a `}` at the end of your script

Comment: Thanks, fixed that..although still  having this issue.